# For any group $(G, \cdot)$, $a, b \in G \iff a \cdot b \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

I want to show this "iff" statement, but I already proved it, so I want to see if my proof is correct. Is the following proof true?

**Caveat:** For clarity and simplification, $a \cdot b = ab.$

### Proof:

This proof uses **Claim #1**, **Claim #2** and **Claim #3** all togther.

Suppose that $G$ is a group. Then consider the following $\sim$ to be defined as $a \sim b\iff ab^{-1} \in G$ on the group $G$.

**Claim #1**: $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

*Proof:*

**Reflexive:** If $a \in G$, then $a \sim a \iff aa^{-1} \in G \iff e \in G$, where $e$ is the identity element in $G$. Since $G$ is a group, $e \in G$. Thus, $a \sim a$.

**Symmetric:** If $a \sim b \Rightarrow ab^{-1} \in G$. But since $G$ is a group, $ba^{-1} = (ab^{-1})^{-1} \in G \Rightarrow b \sim a$.

**Transitive:** If $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, then $ab^{-1}$ and $bc^{-1}$ are in $G$. But G is a group. So, by closure, $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1}) = a(bb^{-1})c^{-1} = aec^{-1} = (ae)c^{-1} = ac^{-1} \in G$. Thus, $a \sim c$.

Hence, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. **QED**

---

Now, I want to show that $[a] = \{m \in G : m \sim a\} = G$. To show this, $[a] \subseteq G$ and $G \subseteq [a]$ is true, for all $a \in G$.

**Claim #2:** $[a] = G, \forall a \in G$

*Proof:*

So, suppose that $x \in [a]$. Since $e \in [a]$ (because $ae^{-1} = ae = a \in G$), then $[a] = [e]$. So, $x \in [a] \iff x \in [e] \iff x \sim e \iff x = xe = xe^{-1} \in G \iff x \in G$.

$\therefore [a] \subseteq G$ and $G \subseteq [a]$ (by going backwards). **QED**

---

**Claim #3:** $a, b \in G \iff ab \in G$

*Proof*:

To prove the "$\iff$" statement said in the title, first, let's start with the conditional.

1. That is, suppose that $a, b \in G$. Then, $ab \in G$ is trivial because $G$ is a group (by closure, one of the requirements to be a group).

Now with the converse:

2. Suppose that $ab \in G$. Then $ab \in G \Rightarrow a(b^{-1})^{-1} \in G \Rightarrow a \sim b^{-1} \Rightarrow a \in [a]$ and $b^{-1} \in [a] \Rightarrow a \in G$ and $(b^{-1})^{-1} = b \in G$ (because if $b^{-1} \in G$, then the inverse of $b^{-1}$ is in $G$). **QED**

## Edit (Jan/05/22):

I just changed a few things for clarity. The reason is to make no more confusion.

Comment: The statement in the title is incomplete or incorrect. You do not say where $a$ and $b$ are taken from. As written, with no indication of where they come from, it is false. For example, let $G$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero rationals. Let $a=\pi$ and $b=\frac{1}{\pi}$. Then $ab\in G$, but neither $a$ nor $b$ lie in $G$.

Comment: Your "claim 1" suffers from the same issue. If you don't specify where $a$ and $b$ are being taken from, it is either incomplete, incoherent, or incorrect. An equivalence relation *on what set*?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, do I have to say in "claim #1" that "$\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G$"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I see what you're saying! Thanks!!

Comment: You have to specify the domain of the relation Otherwise, it's like saying "Let $f$ be the function defined by." And it is irrelevant until you fix the issue of the statement you are trying to prove, which right now is not a sentence (it contains unbound variables).

Comment: Yes, technically, you need to be a lot more precise in your definitions for this to be true. If $(G,\cdot)$ is a group, then $\cdot:G\times G\to G$ would mean that $a,b\in G\iff a\cdot b=\cdot(a,b)\in G.$ But as written, it is less clear, because the notation $ab$ could be inherited from a bigger group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks for the aclaration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which shows one of the problems addressed in the comments (see the title). Let $H=GL_n(K)$ the general linear group and $G=SL_n(K)$ be the subgroup of $H$, the special linear group. Then the diagonal matrices
$$
a={\rm diag}(2,2\ldots ,2),\quad b={\rm diag}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\ldots ,\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
satisfy that $ab\in G$, but $a,b\not\in G$. So the title claim is incorrect.

Concerning your edit, where you said "I just changed a few things for clarity": you need to change the title and add this also to your post.

Comment: What is $K$? A field?

Comment: Yes, $K$ is a field ( $K$ as Körper in German).